# python time series plot individual weekdays as lines

Tags: python, matplotlib

For a time series is there an easy way to plot each weekday as a different line plot?  In this example, Sunday is red and the other days are yellow points.  Is there a way to join all the red points with lines - and do so for the other days of the week.
For example:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
ts = pd.DataFrame(pd.Series(np.random.randn(100), index=pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=100)))
ts.columns = ['quantity']
ts['weekday'] = ts.index.weekday_name
colors = dict(zip(ts.weekday.unique(), ['yellow', 'yellow', 'yellow', 'yellow', 'yellow', 'yellow', 'red']))
plt.scatter(x = ts.index, y = ts.quantity, color=ts.weekday.map(lambda x: colors[x]))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to group the dataframe by `weekday` and `apply` line plot for each group. Hopefully this is what you want:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

ts = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100),
                  index=pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=100),
                  columns=['quantity'])
ts['weekday'] = ts.index.weekday_name
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ts.groupby('weekday').agg(lambda x: x['quantity'].plot(ax=ax,
                                                       legend=True,
                                                       label=x['weekday'][0]))
plt.show()
```

[image]

## Edit: Sort weekdays from Monday to Sunday

The key change here is to use `weekday` rather than `weekday_name` since Pandas has it coded as "Monday=0, Sunday=6". Then you will need to label them with `weekday_name` during plotting:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

ts = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100),
                  index=pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=100),
                  columns=['quantity'])
ts['weekday'] = ts.index.weekday
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ts.groupby('weekday').agg(lambda x: x['quantity'].plot(ax=ax,
                                                       legend=True,
                                                       label=x.index.weekday_name[0]))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please help remove the duplicate Friday and have the days in order.

Comment: Sorry, my fault. I didn't notice that [`apply1 calls `func` twice on the first group](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html). Please check my updates.

Comment: I've tried unsuccessfully setting weekday as categorical and sorting to have the days in order - a workaround is adding a prefix number (1..7) before the weekday name to have them in order.  Is there a better way to sort the weekday names in the legend?

Comment: Workaround - using handles and labels from the legend `handles, labels = ax4.get_legend_handles_labels()` and then doing a manual sort of both handles and labels seperately.

Comment: @Vlad Sorry for missing that in your first comment. Both workarounds are great. I would personally prefer using weekday number since it sounds like the groups, lines, colors and legends are consistent in order. Please check my edit for the simplest code changes I can think about. Sorting just the legend is also a good solution.